# react-beautiful-dnd inside react-draggable component dragging items problem

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I have a draggable dialog component(dragging using react-draggable), inside the dialog I have a list with draggable list items (dragging using  react-beautiful-dnd). The problem is when I'm starting dragging a list item it moves somewhere on the right and down. If I make the parent component(dialog) not draggable, the items begin dragging with no problems. Does anyone know what is the reason of this behavior?
Here is my example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-lewin-qgiumr?file=/src/DraggableDialog.js